# Jquery/JS script to handle multiple selection on my JSP Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets, model-view-controller

On my JSP Page have select field like this, Need to write a script- SCript should be like sending value from front end as per user selection. If selected is ALL US than all 4 entries should be selected, If all NJ than all inside NJ Should be selected and sent back to database in sql query.

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="SelectRegion" name="SelectRegion">
<option value="0" selected="selected">All(US)</option>
<option value="00001">All (NJ) </option>
<option value="123">Ship -1008 (NJ - 123) </option>
<option value="234">Ship -4120 (NJ - 234) </option>
<option value="00040">All (CA) </option>
<option value="345">Ship -1008 (CA - 345) </option>
<option value="567">Ship -4120 (CA - 567) </option>
</select>
```

Comment: To add more clarity to my question- If am selecting in front end All(US) in this case 123,234,345,567 should get selected and sent back to my servlet, where in if am selecting All(NJ) in this case 123, 234 should get selected and same goes to servlet. I also have option to choose any one or more than one ship location for ex 123, 567 in this case these both value goes to servlet.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to hardcode the specific values you want selected, then you can just set the values of your select tag directly using jQuery like so:

```
if ($("#SelectRegion").val() == 0) {
    $("#SelectRegion").val(["123", "234", "345", "567"]);
}
```

Otherwise, you can add a class name to the elements for US and NJ and have some jQuery trigger whatever event you would like to select them dynamically:

```
if ($("#SelectRegion").val() == 0) {
    $('.US').prop("selected", true);
}
```

If you don't necessarily need the selection reflected on the front end and just need the corresponding values, then you can again use class names to iterate through the values:

```
if ($("#SelectRegion").val() == 0) {
  $(".US").each(function() {
      // do something
  });
}
```